This causes error in php file shell_exec('/home/cjm/.local/bin/yt-dlp')
shell_exec('/home/cjm/.local/bin/yt-dlp')

causes this error:
yt-dlp: error: You must provide at least one URL.
Type yt-dlp --help to see a list of all options.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/cjm/.local/bin/yt-dlp", line 5, in <module>
    from yt_dlp import main
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'yt_dlp'

Why does the .(dot) cause a problem in php's shell_exec, the command works fine in the Terminal

Judging from the error message (and the synopsys: yt-dlp [OPTIONS] [--] URL [URL...]), you're not feeding a URL to the script?
